# How would I check if a sender has the MANAGE_ROLES permission in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm currently working on a bot for discord and I have run into a problem that no matter what I have tried to check if the sender of a command has a certain permission before running. But everything I have tried just let's anyone or no one. I've searched so much around the internet and I don't know how to do it.

Here is my code: https://replit.com/@AwesomeKalin55/KawahivaBot#commands/admin/verify.js

Please note that the checking code is removed.
Thanks in advance.

P.S. the command I want to check is `k!verify`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if `message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_ROLES')` is true.

[`message.member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=member) returns the author of the message as a guild member. `GuildMember`s have a [`hasPermission`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=hasPermission) method. With this, you can check if any of this member's roles have a certain permission.